# How do I properly close a socket if I need to reuse the same port?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp, server

I created a server program and a client program in which my goal is for the client to send the server TCP packets. In my case, the client is given the IP address of the server and the port to where the packet should be sent. If I run the server code the first time for a specific port, the server program will search for a response. If I run it twice or more, I get the error "address already in use". It seems as if the socket is not properly closing.

As shown in my code, I have tried sock.shutdown() and sock.close() at the end of my program to no avail. I have also tried adding connection.close() and sock.setsockopt() however, I believe I may be confusing Python 2 with Python 3 syntax. (I am using Python 3) Adding or removing these methods results in the same error. I have posted the server code below for reference.

```
import socket

# TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('10.0.2.6', 2104)
print('Starting up {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) # Allows address to be reused
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections, looking for one connection.
sock.listen(1) # The number of queried connections.

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print('connection from', client_address)

        # Receive the data in small chunks and then send back
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(90)
            print('received {!r}'.format(data))
            if data:
                print('sending data back to the client')
                connection.sendall(data)
                break

            else:
                print('no data from', client_address)
                break

    finally:

        print("Closing current connection") # Cleans up the connection
        connection.close()
        sock.shutdown(socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.AF_NET)
        sock.shutdown(1)
        sock.close()
```

I expect the program to continue to listen on the same part with multiple executions. However, running this code once gives me the error

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use.
```

Comment: It's not about how you close it, it's about how you open it You need to set the SO_REUSEADDR option on the listen socket before you bind it.

Comment: @user207421 Just to make sure, is SO_REUSEADDR valid in Python 3? I will flip the bind and listen methods. And by just doing sock.listen(), am I not already setting the SO_REUSEADDR option as I did sock.setsockopt() a few lines before? EDIT: Actually just tested sock.listen() before sock.bind(). I get [Errno 22] Invalid Argument

Comment: I don't know Python but I would be astonished if it wasn't supported. No, `listen()` doesn't already do that. And you can't listen before bind. No idea why you even tried it: it doesn't make the least sense.

Comment: @user207421 I am a bit new to Python. I thought you saying that setting the SO_REUSEADDR option on the listening socket meant listen goes before bind. Anyhow, haven't I already set the proper sock options in line 10? I am not following the logic.

Comment: `sock.shutdown(socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.AF_NET)` doesn't make any sense and will throw an attribute error exception at runtime. I'm guessing the code posted is not the code you've actually run.